# How should I interpret the double summation sign?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, notation, clustering

I am reading [this paper on the Hierarchical Clustering](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/11/5/2373).

The author introduces cluster intra-compactness indicator and it is formulated as follows

$$RR_{intra}(S) = \sum_{i \in D \\ C_{k} \in S | i \in C_{k}}p_{i}' * RR_{i, C_{k}\setminus i},$$
where $D$ is the set of diagnoses, $i$ is the index of some diagnosis, $p_i$ is the empirical probability of a diagnosis occurrence. $S = \{C_1, \ldots,C_N\}$ is the clustering solution of a set of $N$ clusters denoted $C_k$, $k \in\{1, \ldots, N\}$, $RR$ is the relative risk.

I understand the formula within, but I do not understand how to interpret two summation indices stuck under each other? Any hints?

Comment: I am not quite sure (because of that horizontal line between $S$ and $i$), however it is probably lazy notation for: 'sum over all $i$ and $C_k$ that fulfill $i \in D \wedge C_k \in S$ where $i \in C_k$' or equivalently $i \in D \cap C_k \wedge C_k \in S$.

Comment: A double summation would be $\Sigma \Sigma$; this is just an ordinary summation :)  The stacked arguments underneath the summation sign mean that each argument must hold.  So, the first line says that you are summing over all diagnoses ($i\in D$) and the second line says you are summing *also* over all clusters in $S$ for which diagnosis $i$ lies in the cluster.  So, if diagnosis $1$ lay in cluster $1$ but not cluster $2$ you would see $C_1$ involved in the $i=1$ term of the sum, but not in the $i=2$ term.

Comment: I believe this is double sum, first index is $i$ taking all values from $D$, and second index is $C_k$ taking all values from $S$ such that $i\in C_k$.